# 16.04LTS XServer quit working

Tags: auto-login

I've been happily running Ubuntu 16.04LTS for a few months now, and until this morning, no problems. When I booted up today, instead of automatically logging me in to the Gnome environment, it asked me for my password. 
     After scrambling to find out where I wrote it down, I managed to find it. When I entered the password, I got a quick "System error detected" window with "Report or Cancel" as choices, but the window closed very quickly. I tried hitting the "Report" key, but it just closed the window anyway.
     I've run the background backup that was part of the system religiously.

```
 I rebooted to the non-GUI password prompt, then hit ctrl-alt-f1 and got into the textual menu. It did let me log in there, but I don't know what to do to have Ubuntu look for and repair damaged packages. 

 Any help will be most appreciated.
```

UPDATE: I can log into the non-graphical environment. I tried to run startx, and got an error saying something like Nvidea module won't load. Is there a way to reinstall the Xserver system? Wonder why all of a sudden the Xserver quit working and the Nvidea drivers won't load?

Jim Darrough, Oklahoma

Comment: So In can get startx to work from the terminal prompt. Some programs show on the GUI, but many little icons are missing. I can run others from a terminal, however, but some don't have the option to exit sudo thunderbird, for example). There are many backups, but I can't get duplicity to restore any of the incrementals. Gives me an error every time. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, I am really in a pickle from attempting to restore the xserver. Now it's unusable. So, is there some way to do a system restore with deja-dup? I copied the entire deja-dup directory to a USB drive.

Comment: Yes! I have a  working X again! Found a reference online to reinstallation of the Ubuntu Desktop, and when I ran it, voila!